# What if 2/3 of the validators are malicious in tendermint and a fraudlent transaction takes place?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin, tendermint

So, i have this condition where 2/3 of the validators are not honest and they can carry out a fraud transaction.
What can be done to prevent it and how do i know which 2/3 are fraud?
PBFT isn't working out then, right?

What if 2/3 are not honest?

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If more than 2/3 of validators are malicious, there's not much hope. Expect maybe for minority to fork out.

We're currently working on [#200](https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/issues/200) which is suppose to help address the case where 1/3+ of validators are malicious. "We need to boot into a "recovery mode" protocol so validators can publish evidence, find out who shit the bed, kick them out and restart". You can read more on proof of fork accountability [here](https://github.com/tendermint/tendermint/wiki/Byzantine-Consensus-Algorithm#proof-of-fork-accountability)